# При парсинге Яндекс Новостей выдает не свежую новость

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Проблема заключается в том, что при работе кода, выдает почему то новости которые небыли указаны вообще, я код еще не дописал, но работоспособность решил проверить и вот такая тут проблема, пытаюсь парсить новости от туда с хештегом Москва река.

```
from turtle import Turtle
from requests import request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://newssearch.yandex.ru/news/search?text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0&sortby=date"

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

post = soup.find("h1", class_="mg-aria-label")

post1 = soup.find("a",  ="mg-snippet__url")

print(post1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://newssearch.yandex.ru/news/' \
      'search?text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0&sortby=date'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
postes = soup.findAll("article", class_="news-search-story news-search__main-item mg-grid__item")

for post in postes:
    title = post.a.text
    url = post.a['href']
    print(title)
    print(url)

Мосводосток обследовал реку Лихоборку после жалоб на сине-фиолетовую воду
https://www.msk.kp.ru/online/news/4763438/?utm_source=yxnews&utm_medium=desktop&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fyandex.ru%2Fnews%2Fsearch%3Ftext%3D
В Москве река окрасилась в сине-фиолетовый
https://mockva.ru/2022/05/26/365391.html?utm_source=yxnews&utm_medium=desktop&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fyandex.ru%2Fnews%2Fsearch%3Ftext%3D
В Москве появилась фиолетовая река
https://www.avtoradio.ru/news/uid/256461?utm_source=yxnews&utm_medium=desktop&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fyandex.ru%2Fnews%2Fsearch%3Ftext%3D
....
```