# Выборка по постам Python Telegram

Tags: python, бот, telegram

Всем привет, очень нужна помощь народа!

У меня есть скрипт на Python который собирает новости с указанных мною Московских ТГ каналов, но мне нужно, что бы скрипт отправлял мне не все подряд посты, а посты которые затрагивают Москву реку, как это возможно реализовать ?

Вот мой скрипт который отправляет мне новости с тг каналов в мой тг канал

```
from telethon import functions, types
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync


api_id = №№№№№№№№
api_hash = №№№№№№№№№№№
client = TelegramClient("test", api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
print("STARTED")
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=["moscowach", "moscowtop", 
                            "moscowlenta", "DtRoad", "mosmap", "kim_online_rus"]))
async def normal_handler(event):
        if isinstance(event.chat, types.Channel):
            username = event.chat.username
            rdy = "@" + str(username)
            await client.send_message("https://t.me/kek3214", rdy)
            await client.send_message("https://t.me/kek3214", event.message)
        
        
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1411914/178576)?

Comment: что хранится в `event.message` ? если это текст сообщения в виде строки, добавьте проверку вхождения вашего ключевого слова в него

Comment: Нет, это не дубликат

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin нет, это не дубликат

Comment: @maestro ну, получается что как поделится постом работает, но я попробую, спасибо :)